# How to delete all files in the ADO Agent.BuildDirectory and its subdirectories using the DeleteFiles task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Using the Azure DevOps pipeline task `DeleteFiles` I would like to remove all files in agent build folder `Agent.BuildDirectory` and any subfolder - at any deeper level - with a specific file extension, f.e. **.app**. Setting the task to the following does not work:

```
- task: DeleteFiles@1
  displayName: "Remove all *.app files from Agent.BuildDirectory"
    inputs:
      sourcefolder: $(Agent.BuildDirectory)
      contents: '*.app'
```

Now how can I get this working?

Comment: try this syntax: `**/*.app`

Comment: Not doing the job fully. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Your example would only remove all `.app` files from the build directory. To remove those files from subfolders, you'd need something like:

```yaml
- task: DeleteFiles@1
  displayName: "Remove all *.app files from Agent.BuildDirectory - and child folders"
    inputs:
      sourcefolder: $(Agent.BuildDirectory)
      contents: '**/*.app'
```

Comment: Not doing the job fully. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Have been working on this the whole day, and the syntax `**/*.app` is not working. It does not remove all files in the all subfolders.

I am getting lost on this.

`**/*.app` was already in my original `DeleteFiles` task and my subfolders did get cluttered with all old .app files. After the responses above I tried it again and it seemed that the .app files I was focusing on did get removed, but studying it closer not all got removed. As the subfolder structure in the `Agent.BuildDirectory` is a somewhat complex one, it is hard to check all of them. The subfolder is related to all the linked pipelines. For each pipeline the artifacts are downloaded, so, for each a sub folder is created, containing subfolders on their own.